# Как вывести максимальное число из этих двух PHP?

Tags: php

Есть две переменные $a и $b, значения которых числа. Как вывести максимальное число из этих двух?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
echo $a > $b ? $b : $a;
```

Или так:

```
if ($a > $b){
    echo $a;
} else {
    echo $b;
}
```

Comment: Выдаст $b при $a = $b

Answer (score 7):

Функция [max()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.max.php)

```
echo max($a, $b);
```